# Dart VM fails to build on windows

Tags: dart

I am trying to buiil Dart-VM on windows, I follow the steps as described here

https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/wiki/Building
When I run the build.py command as below:

> .\tools\build.py --mode release --arch x64 create_sdk

I get the following error:

```
gn gen --check in out\ReleaseX64
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\ops\dart\sdk\tools\gn.py", line 436, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "D:\ops\dart\sdk\tools\gn.py", line 423, in main
    results = pool.map(run_command, commands, chunksize=1)
  File "C:\app\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 251, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "C:\app\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 567, in get
    raise self._value
WindowsError: [Error 2] System cannot find file。

Tried to run GN, but it failed. Try running it manually:
        $ python D:\ops\dart\sdk\tools\gn.py -m release -a x64 --os host -v
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\ops\dart\sdk\tools\build.py", line 658, in <module>
    sys.exit(Main())
  File "D:\ops\dart\sdk\tools\build.py", line 651, in Main
    mode, arch, cross_build) != 0:
  File "D:\ops\dart\sdk\tools\build.py", line 491, in BuildOneConfig
    args = BuildNinjaCommand(options, target, target_os, mode, arch)
  File "D:\ops\dart\sdk\tools\build.py", line 473, in BuildNinjaCommand
    if UseGoma(out_dir):
  File "D:\ops\dart\sdk\tools\build.py", line 431, in UseGoma
    return 'use_goma = true' in open(args_gn, 'r').read()
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'out\\ReleaseX64\\args.gn'
```

It seems missing the args.gn file in out\ReleaseX64 folder. but I cannot find args.gn in Dart source folders. Is it generated during building process? whether I do wrong steps led to no such file generated?

Comment: Try with everything on drive c:

Comment: Thanks your reply, but I get same error after move every thing on drive c: and build again.